# save_warmup in Pystan

Tags: stan, pystan

I've been using Stan for a bit through Pystan and is really nice. Just recently however I tried to reduce the size of the output (particularly, the generated_quantities bit) using the same syntax than in STAN, by declaring `save_warmup=False`. However, when digging a bit into PyStan code I noticed that this is currently hard coded and not able to edit using the control argument (the dictionary that handles extra parameters in Pystan). I'm tempted to modify the source code directly, but just wondering if is something PyStan devs are currently considering.

Cheers and thanks for an amazing work! (both PyStan and Stan!)

Comment: Interesting question! There is a slot for `save_warmup` in `cdef struct sampling_t` in stan_fit.pxd, although it says there that it is always true, which is so if one looks at the Python side. On top, in `get_ctrl_sampling_save_warmup`, used in the caller, one finds it is also hardcoded to true. Why? Does anything break if different?